# No need for export when running functions in subshell

Tags: bash, shell-script, export, daemon, pid

I have a `msource.sh` script that will be sourced:

```
$ cat msource.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "($BASHPID) - sourced ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" &>> "$logfile"
  # logfile is defined by the sourcing script
sourced_var="init sourced var with $BASHPID"
```

I have a script that will source `msource.sh` and call a `function` as is and in a `subshell`. It will then call another script `mscript2.sh`:

```
$ cat mscript.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env sh

logfile=mout.out
rm -f $logfile
source msource.sh

mfun() {
  echo "($BASHPID) in ${FUNCNAME}"  &>> "$logfile"
  echo "  avar: '$avar'" &>> "$logfile"
  echo "  sourced_var: '$sourced_var'" &>> "$logfile"
}

avar="$BASHPID - init"

echo "[mfun] basic call" &>> "$logfile"
mfun

echo -e "\n[mfun &] subshell call" &>> "$logfile"
mfun &
wait $!

## call mscript2.sh
echo -e "\n[mscript2] background call" &>> "$logfile"
bash mscript2.sh &
wait $!

# call mscript2.sh after exporting variables
echo -e "\n[mscript2 &] export and background call" &>> "$logfile"
export logfile
export avar
export sourced_var
bash mscript2.sh &
wait $!
```

I have another script, `mscript2.sh` that will be called by `mscript.sh`, as seen above:

```
$ cat mscript2.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

[ -z "${logfile:+x}" ] && logfile=mout2.out || true

echo "($BASHPID) - executing ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" &>> "$logfile"
echo "  avar: '$avar'" &>> "$logfile"
echo "  sourced_var: '$sourced_var'" &>> "$logfile"
```

I run everything:

```
$ bash script.sh
```

I get the following outputs:

```
$ cat mout.out 
(13166) - sourced msource.sh
[mfun] basic call
(13166) in mfun
  avar: '13166 - init'
  sourced_var: 'init sourced var with 13166'

[mfun &] subshell call
(13174) in mfun
  avar: '13166 - init'
  sourced_var: 'init sourced var with 13166'

[mscript2 &] background call

[mscript2 &] export and background call
(13184) - executing mscript2.sh
  avar: '13166 - init'
  sourced_var: 'init sourced var with 13166'
```

and

```
$ cat mout2.out 
(13179) - executing mscript2.sh
  avar: ''
  sourced_var: ''
```

So if I call the function as is, the `pid` is the same and I don't need to source the `msource.sh` nor to export the variables.
If I call the function in a `subshell`, sourcing `msource.sh` or exporting variables still is not required.

However, calling another script in a`subshell` loses all the variables and they need to be exported, even the logfile which will be redefined otherwise.

Can someone clarify what's going on? What's the difference between executing a function in a `subshell` and executing another script, that will also be launched in another `subshell`? Why don't a parent process' variables have to be exported to be passed to a `subshell`ed function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138498/108618) on Unix & Linux SE explains the issue. The main point is:

> A subshell is […] different from executing a script.